# Windows Search service, mixed clients - what to choose?

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, search, indexing

I have been given the task to implement the traditional Windows 2008 R2 Search services on an existing Win2008 R2 file server. Sure, no problem I was thinking, just add the role service and then it should be a walk in the park.

Then I discovered that I have to support both XP and Win7 clients. And as far as I know, Windows Search Service is only for Win7/2008 R2 search clients, XP needs the older Indexing Service.

So my simple question is this, what should I do in order to enable indexing and speed up search requests from the clients, to support both XP and Win7?